# Writing to an array if a condition is true

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to write only the rows which contains Atom_No 1 to arrays x_o,y_o.. but I got out of bound error. x contains 678 elements and the shape of X_o is 226. Atom_No looks like this [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3...]. I want coordinates that correspond to the ones.

```
ii=0
x_o=numpy.zeros((226))
y_o=numpy.zeros((226))
z_o=numpy.zeros((226))
for i in range(678):
    if (Atom_No[i]==1):
        ii=ii+1
        x_o[ii]=x[ii]
        y_o[ii]=y[ii]
        z_o[ii]=z[ii]
```

IndexError: index 226 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 226

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At your last iteration, you have

```
ii = 226
```

because it match one third of your conditions (678/3)

and you try to access the element

```
x[226]
```

which doesn't exist (the last index is 225, Python uses a zero indexing)

I think what will work for you is the following:

```
for i in range(678):
    if (Atom_No[i]==1):       
        x_o[ii]=x[ii]
        y_o[ii]=y[ii]
        z_o[ii]=z[ii]
        ii=ii+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is meant to be vectorized to avoid for-loops.  The one you have above could be replaced by using Boolean masks:

```
hits = Atom_No == 1
x_o, y_o, z_o = x[hits], y[hits], z[hits]
```

This way you don't even have to pre-allocate the `x_o, y_o, z_o` arrays, they just get created as needed.

(Edit: I should add that your code/question is a bit incomplete so I may have misinterpreted the array sizes)